# Incorrect reading of property required of the table field

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, recordset

i'm having trouble reading the property "Required", of a field from an Access table.
In the Access table the property "Required" is set to TRUE

I am reading the property through a recordset as shown below

```vba
Set MyRecordset = AppDatabaseDB.OpenRecordset("select * from my_table;", dbOpenDynaset)
For MyIndex = 0 To MyRecordset.Fields.Count - 1
    Debug.Print "Name: " & MyRecordset(MyIndex).Name
    Debug.Print "Required: " & MyRecordset(MyIndex).Required
Next
```

When the field name length is up to 41 characters, the above command works perfectly.
Example:

```vba
Field name = scr11_modelo_do_produto_descricao_do_prod
```

However when the field name is longer than 41 characters, the above code (`MyRecordset(MyIndex).Required`) always returns `FALSE`

Example:

```vba
Field name = scr11_modelo_do_produto_descricao_do_product
```

Reading the specification of Access tables, I found that the number of characters in the field name can be up to 64 characters.

I ask for help in knowing what the problem is. What may be happening so that the property does not return the correct value and why is the length of the name influencing the result?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to analyze a table's structure, don't use a recordset! Use a TableDef instead. A recordset only loads what's relevant to it, while a tabledef loads the entire structure.

```
Set td = AppDatabaseDB.TableDefs("my_table")
For MyIndex = 0 To td.Fields.Count - 1
    Debug.Print "Name: " & MyRecordset(MyIndex).Name
    Debug.Print "Required: " & MyRecordset(MyIndex).Required
Next
```

Also note: when accessed through a TableDef, `.Required` is read-write. When accessed through a Recordset, `.Required` is read-only.

Comment: Hi Erik A,
thanks for your help.
I even did a test using TableDefs instead of Recordset. However, for the logic I defined in my program, using the recordset would be much simpler.I would like to understand what is really going on. Is it usual, or am I making a mistake using a recordset for this purpose?

Comment: @Marcos Using a recordset to analyze field properties is a risk, because they may or may not be initialized depending on a variety of conditions. As an alternative, you can use the `Properties` collection  of a field to explicitly fetch properties, but that adds some code. Another alternative is using ADOX, but if you're using DAO that's not recommended.

Comment: Erik, Thanks for the comments, using the TableDef instead of Recordset seems to be the best option. Thanks a lot for the help